# Dismiss Keyboard When Leaving FormSheet View?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, keyboard

I have a UINavigationController which uses Form Sheet views and I have viewController 1 which pushes viewController2.

viewController2 has a UITextField and the keyboard pops up, great. However upon popping this view and going back to viewController1 the keyboard stays up and I just can't get it to dismiss.

I just want the keyboard to dismiss when returning to viewController1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second view controller in the `viewWillDisappear:` method do this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This will take the focus from the text field and that results in the keyboard being dismissed.

Comment: No luck. Doesn't work, keyboard stays up when retuning to viewController1.

Comment: The issue is that it needs to actually be: `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` which I have tried also, it is called, but not working for me.

Comment: Oh sorry. And I guess you changed `textField` to your variable and checked that it's not `nil`? Sorry, I have to ask :)

Comment: Yeah, positive, its my variable and all hooked up in interface builder

Comment: Do you call `super` in `viewWillDisappear:`?

Comment: I've discovered that `resignFirstResponder` removes the focus from the textfield however the keyboard stays up.

Comment: Is is possible that an other text field becomes the first responder? Usually when a text field resigns, the keyboard should dismiss.

Comment: Nope, not possible, its literally the only textfield I have. Nice thought though.